# Detecting when two objects are overlapping each other in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a snake game and I'm trying to figure out how to get the program to detect when 2 objects are overlapping each other. I tried using using `canvas.find_overlapping`, but it only works when I run my code.

Here is my code below:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

class snake:
    def __init__(self):
       self.apple = canvas.create_rectangle(70+100, 70+100, 100+100, 100+100, fill="red")
       self.snake = canvas.create_rectangle(50,50,100,100,fill="white",outline= "white")
       canvas.bind_all('<Left>', self.Left)
       canvas.bind_all('<Right>',self.Right)
       canvas.bind_all('<Up>', self.Up)
       canvas.bind_all('<Down>', self.Down)
       pos = canvas.coords(self.snake)
       if canvas.find_overlapping(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3] >= (self.apple)):
           canvas.move(self.apple, random.randint(0, 750), random.randint(0, 850))

    def Left(self, event):
        if event.keysym == 'Left':
            canvas.move(self.snake, -20, 0)
    def Right(self, event):
        if event.keysym == 'Right':
            canvas.move(self.snake, 20, 0)
    def Up(self, event):
        if event.keysym == 'Up':
            canvas.move(self.snake, 0, -20)
    def Down(self,event):
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            canvas.move(self.snake,0,20)


tk =Tk()
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=800,height=900,bg= "lightblue")

Snake = snake()
while True:
    time.sleep(1/60)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code in your question.

Comment: What do you mean it only works when you run your code — isn't that what you want? Also note you should generally only call `mainloop()` once in tkinter applications.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- If you're checking the key in the callback, you can use the same callback for all key presses
- The find_overlapping() method must be called each time the snake is moved
- find_overlapping returns a widget index list, so check if the apple index is in the overlap list
- Use the coords method to move a widget to absolute coordinates

Here is the updated code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

class snake:
    def __init__(self):
       self.apple = canvas.create_rectangle(70+100, 70+100, 100+100, 100+100, fill="red")
       self.snake = canvas.create_rectangle(50,50,100,100,fill="white",outline= "white")
       canvas.bind_all('<Left>', self.KeyCheck)
       canvas.bind_all('<Right>',self.KeyCheck)
       canvas.bind_all('<Up>', self.KeyCheck)
       canvas.bind_all('<Down>', self.KeyCheck)
           
    def CheckOverlap(self):
       pos = canvas.coords(self.snake)
       if self.apple in canvas.find_overlapping(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3]):
           x = random.randint(0, 750)
           y = random.randint(0, 850)
           canvas.coords(self.apple, x, y, x+30, y+30)
        
    def KeyCheck(self, event):
        if event.keysym == 'Left':
            canvas.move(self.snake, -20, 0)
        if event.keysym == 'Right':
            canvas.move(self.snake, 20, 0)
        if event.keysym == 'Up':
            canvas.move(self.snake, 0, -20)
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            canvas.move(self.snake,0,20)
        self.CheckOverlap()
  
tk =Tk()
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=800,height=900,bg= "lightblue")

Snake = snake()
while True:
    time.sleep(1/60)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: Better change the while block to `tk.mainloop()`, and call `canvas.pack()` after `canvas=Canvas(...)`.

Comment: thank you @Mike67 for your response just one question what is the x+30 and y+30 mean or do

Comment: Sorry for the delay - 30 is the height and width of the apple